# Why arrow head not shown for this code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
\node (v3) at (4, 0) {$v_3$};
\node (v5) at (2, -2) {$v_5$};
\draw [->] (v3)--(v5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The above code gives me:

[image] Where there is no arrow head.

But if you change the coordinate of `(v5)`, like `(3,-1.5)`, then I will have:

[image] Where a very tiny arrow head appears at node `(v5)`.

Am I missing something? Thanks

EDIT: as suggested by @Cmhughes,

I installed texlive from `ubuntu 13.04` official repo. And

`\listfiles` outputs:

```
 *File List*
     nag.sty    2011/11/25 0.7 warning about old commands (ulmi)
nag-l2tabu.cfg    2010/05/17 v2.11 l2tabu rules for nag.sty (ulmi)
nag-orthodox.cfg    2006/04/19 v1.8 strict rules for nag.sty (ulmi)
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
hyperref.sty    2012/05/13 v6.82q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/05/13 v6.82q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2012/05/13 v6.82q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: your first snippet, when posted into a complete MWE, works fine for me, and gives me an arrow- perhaps an update is in order.[How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) Please add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}` and post it to your question :) [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: @cmhughes I was lazy, so I just install from ubuntu official repo using `apt-get texlive-full`.  So it might be due to some outdated packages in the repo?  I will try downloading the Texlive from [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive).

Comment: Yes indeedyo- see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092). Alternatively, you could do some tweaking as described in [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163682). I follow the details in the first link, and it has worked for me every time. Once you have an update, let us know- when you've confirmed everything is good, we'll probably close this question :)

Comment: I think Ubuntu 12.04 repos have only TeXLive 2009. So, you might want to update.

Comment: @kan Oops, it's on `ubuntu 13.04`.  I've updated that.  I assume that ubuntu has updated their repo for 13.04.

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks.  I'll sort this out asap.